# I Want to add object has list of object in firebase ,flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have object "Lawer" has List of objects "maker"

```
class Lawer{   

   final int x1;
   final int x2;
   final int x3;
   final List<Maker>objects
  Lawer({this.x1,this.x2,this.x3 ,this.objects});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
      {
        'x1':1 ,
        'x2':1,
        'x3':2,     
      };
}
class Maker{
  final String lawerID;
  final String customerID;
  final bool connect;
  Maker({this.lawerID,this.customerID,this.connect=false});
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
      {
   'lawerID':lawerID,
   'customerID':customerID,
   'connect':connect,
      };
}
```

```
CollectionReference dPReplies=FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('lawers');     FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction tx)async {
    var result=await dPReplies.add(lawer.toJson())
 });
```

how to save this object in firebase"save object have some variables and list of objects"

Answer (score 1):

1. Change this in your class:

   ```
   Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
      {
        'x1':x1,
        'x2':x2,
        'x3':x3,     
      };
   ```
2. You need to capitalize `Lawer`

   ```
   var result= await dPReplies.add(Lawer.toJson()) //instead of lawer.toJson
   ```

Comment: this work very well with me when adding simple object but I have to save object have list of another object in the same object

Comment: Did it answer your question?

Comment: no, I have the same problem have to object "lawyer" containing a list of objects List<Maker> and want to save it in fire base

Comment: You didn't post that in your question, add the `Maker` class so we can see how it looks, and that also should be converted to a Map, just like the others.

Comment: class Maker{
  final String lawerID;
  final String customerID;
  final bool connect;
  Maker({this.lawerID,this.customerID,this.connect=false});
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
      {
   'lawerID':lawerID,
   'customerID':customerID,
   'connect':connect,
      };
}